# Redux queries causing UI flicker on each render

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

I've been having a lot of troubles suddenly with UI flicker using redux queries. See video here: https://files.catbox.moe/5bbs0h.mov

The text that you see flickering is data fetched by a redux query.

```
const {data: messages, isSuccess: isMessagesSuccess} = useGetMessagesQuery(
  {id: convoId, isGroup: isGroup},
);
```

After that I check for success and set the relevant data to a state.

```
const [recentMessage, setRecentMessage] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  if (isMessagesSuccess) {
    setRecentMessage(messages[messages.length - 1]);
  }
}, [messages]);
```

It seems that every time the component gets re-rendered, the text disappears then is repopulated. I've handle the query data in this very same way in other areas of the app, but never have an issue. Any insight as to what's going on? And/or some best practise tips regarding using redux queries?

Answer (score 0):

> Redux queries causing UI flicker on each render ?

This can come from plenty reasons, is it possible to share a reproduction example ?

If this came from redux instead of setting results with a hook (which trigger another re-render)

You can use a selector instead:

```
const {data: messages, isSuccess: isMessagesSuccess} = useGetMessagesQuery(
  {id: convoId, isGroup: isGroup},
  { selectFromResult: (result) => result.data[result.data.length - 1] }
);
```

Comment: When I hardcoded the data that the query provides, the flickering goes away, which is what led me to blaming redux in this case. I'll get a reproduction up in a few!